# Rendering Text Calendar

Tags: python, datetime, mutation

I have a function which is supposed to build a header for a calendar like so:

`' Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat '`

It takes a isoweekday (one of '#Monday' 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 '#Sunday').

Here is the code:

```
@staticmethod
def _isoweekday_to_str(isoweekday):
    isoweekday = isoweekday - 1
    isoweekday = str(isoweekday)
    x = datetime.strptime(isoweekday, '%w')
    return x.strftime('%a')

TEXT_CAL_MONTH_WEEK_HEADER = ""

iter_isoweekday = week_start
for _ in range(0,7):
    TEXT_CAL_MONTH_WEEK_HEADER += self._isoweekday_to_str(iter_isoweekday).rjust(TEXT_CAL_CELL_WIDTH, " ")

            if iter_isoweekday != 7:
                iter_isoweekday += 1
            else:
                iter_isoweekday = 1
```

The output I'm getting, when passing in 4 as the week start, is:

`' Mon  Mon  Mon  Mon  Mon  Mon  Mon '`

it should be:

`' Thu  Fri  Sat  Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed '`

I'm really, really not sure what's going on. I think it's either something to do with the way variables are assigned, string mutation, or the datetime library.

UPDATE: it appears that datetime.strptime is the problem. No matter what I pass in, I get datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0) back... which, you guessed it, was a Monday.

Help?

Comment: `datetime.strptime(isoweekday, '%w')` returns `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0)` no matter what `isoweekday` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the localised days of the week from the [calendar module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html):

```
>>> import calendar
>>> list(calendar.day_name)
['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

Or the abbreviated names, using [**`calendar.day_abbr`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_abbr):

```
>>> ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.LocaleTextCalendar) if you need other locales.

Obviously, the module can produce whole calendars:

```
>>> print calendar.TextCalendar().formatmonth(2016, 1)
    January 2016
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Comment: I was looking at the calendar module a while ago actually... it's my understanding that it doesn't do a good job of producing "custom" calendars, it just basically produces calendars of an entire month/year, but not between ranges. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know. Read the documentation. You can get arrays of all the week days for a month, and format them how you like.

Comment: I did read the docs and that's what I got out of it -- I was wondering if you had some more detailed insight.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do it this way, but you need an actual date to pass to `strptime` rather than an isoweekday. For example,

```
from datetime import datetime
TEXT_CAL_CELL_WIDTH = 5
def _isoweekday_to_str(isoweekday):
    isoweekday = '1900-01-{:02d}'.format(isoweekday)
    x = datetime.strptime(isoweekday, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return x.strftime('%a')

TEXT_CAL_MONTH_WEEK_HEADER = ""

week_start = 4
iter_isoweekday = week_start
for _ in range(0,7):
    TEXT_CAL_MONTH_WEEK_HEADER += _isoweekday_to_str(iter_isoweekday).rjust(TEXT_CAL_CELL_WIDTH, " ")
    if iter_isoweekday != 7:
        iter_isoweekday += 1
    else:
        iter_isoweekday = 1
print(TEXT_CAL_MONTH_WEEK_HEADER )
```

Output:

```
Thu  Fri  Sat  Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed
```

(This works because 01/01/1900 was a Monday).

But why not do something similar with a dictionary of day names:

```
day_names = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
def weekday_header(week_start):
    header = ''.join(['{:4s}'.format(day_names[(day_number+week_start) % 7])
                     for day_number in range(7)])
    return header

print(weekday_header(4))
```

Comment: It was because of the localization, which the other answerer also helped with :)